Does this serie convergent?$\sum_{m\geq 4}\frac{\zeta(3/2)}{\zeta(3)}\frac{\zeta(4/2)}{\zeta(4)}\dots\frac{\zeta((m-1)/2)}{\zeta(m-1)}(\zeta(m/2)-1)$
I want to know whether the serie converges or not, the serie is as following:
$$\sum_{m=4}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(3/2)}{\zeta(3)}\frac{\zeta(4/2)}{\zeta(4)}\dots\frac{\zeta((m-1)/2)}{\zeta(m-1)}(\zeta(m/2)-1)$$
I try to use the trivial bound of $\zeta(n)$ like :
$$\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}<|\zeta(s)|<\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-1}, \sigma>1.$$
hence the serie can be simplified by $\ll $ as :
$$\ll \sum_{m=4}^{\infty}m^4(\zeta(m/2)-1).
$$
But I do not know whether it is convergent or not.

Of course it does; $\zeta(m/2)-1\in O(2^{-m/2})$ suffices.

Oh，thanks, I think I get it.
